# I'm not able to load plugins in QGIS due to an error when calling its classFactory()

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I can't manage to load some plugins in QGIS, such as "QDraw". This message always appears and I can't find where the problem lies. How can I solve it?

```
Couldn't load plugin 'qdraw' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:   move(self, QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'   move(self, int, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)   File "/home/XXX/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qdraw/__init__.py", line 22, in classFactory
    return Qdraw(iface)   File "/home/XXX/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qdraw/qdraw.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.settings = QdrawSettings()   File "/home/XXX/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qdraw/qdrawsettings.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.center()   File "/home/XXX/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qdraw/qdrawsettings.py", line 81, in center
    self.move((screen.width() - size.width()) / 2, TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:   move(self, QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'   move(self, int, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'


Python version: 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0]  QGIS version: 3.22.4-Białowieża Białowieża, exported
```

Comment: It's a [bug](https://github.com/jeremyk6/qdraw/issues/8) that was [fixed](https://github.com/jeremyk6/qdraw/pull/12) last year but the plugin hasn't been updated in the QGIS plugin repository since 2021.

Comment: And if you download the zip from the QDraw Github repo and install that, you get [another error](https://github.com/jeremyk6/qdraw/pull/16) which you can manually [fix](https://github.com/jeremyk6/qdraw/pull/16/commits/737f7b1c5ad2b7794d72e2e858ea570d289845e6). But do you need to bother with this abandoned plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the plugin. I suggest you upgrade your QGIS installation to the latest version and upgrade all the plugins you have installed.

In my case, I always upgrade them when receiving a notification.

[image]

Comment: There's no updated version of the Qdraw plugin available.

Comment: I usually prefer not to advise this, but consider re-installing QGIS. Test it at least on another machine perhaps.

Comment: Reinstalling QGIS doesn't affect plugins which are saved in the current QGIS profile folder in the users home directory. Starting QGIS with a new profile can fix some plugin issues , but in this case, the error is the result of a bug in the plugin and no amount of reinstalling or creating new profiles will fix it.